# How to automate QR code from website using selenium java with image or url for qrcode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, qr-code

I have a qr code in my application which does is not an image and also does not have src url, the sample of qr code path is attached [image]

I am not sure how to automate this, I tried adding zxing library but "BufferedImageLuminanceSource" is throwing error as undefined.

Use case is basically to scan the qr code and verify if the url and order number linked to that qr code is correct.